# Installed Snow Leopard on VirtualBox but can't install guest additions

Tags: virtualbox

My host machine is Windows 7. I installed Snow Leopard on VirtualBox but i am having problem installing the guest additions. The guest additions iso is mounted in `/Volumes/VBOXADDITIONS_4`. But if I run the install command `sudo sh ./VBoxLinuxAdditons.run` I get `Unable to determaine library path`.

Is installing guest additions for Mac OS X on VirtualBox even possible?

Comment: The only version of Snow Leopard licensed to virtualise on any host is the server version. That & all versions from Lion upwards are licensed for virtualisation on Apple hardware only. No other usage is permitted by Apple's EULA.

Comment: A workaround would be to create a `*.iso` and insert that. There might be some way to create `*.iso`files on windows like on mac. I have compiled the (mac-)information in an [answer here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/284819/224888).

Answer (score 3):

From [Virtualbox Manual : Chapter 14](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch14.html):

> **14.2. Known Issues**
>   Mac OS X guests:
>   VirtualBox does not provide Guest Additions for Mac OS X at this time

What you are trying to run is the script for Linux distributions. That does not work on OS X due to numerous differences in the system, despite a similar-ish base.

From the content of [this](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=64921), I wouldn't hold out for such support in VirtualBox any time soon.